# Mongo find occurences of a given field with a particular value under different path

Tags: mongodb

I have a JSON structure like this:

```
  {
  "data": {
    "name": "Name",
    "phone": 9876543212,
    "emailId": "email@gmail.com",
    "valobjs": {
      "vals": {
        "val1": {
          "isValid": false,
          "message": "invalid phone number, too many digits"
        },
        "val2": {
          "isValid": true,
          "message": "Validation success"
        },
         "val3": {
          "isValid": false,
          "message": "invalid email-id"
        },
        "val4": {
          "isValid": true,
          "message": "Validation success"
        },
         "val5": {
          "isValid": false,
          "message": "invalid json data"
        },
        "val6": {
          "isValid": false,
          "message": "invalid userid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is I want to find the total count of "isValid": false occurrences in my collection. I am very new with mongo db and I tried with normal aggregations but was not able to as my path is different (data.valobjs.vals.val{integer}).
For example in the above case, the output of query should be 4
as there are 4 entries with "isValid": false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we don't know the name of fields inside `data.valobjs.vals`, we would first convert `data.valobjs.vals` into an array of key-value pairs using [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/). Now, the count of `isValid: false` can be calculated by accessing the values from that array.

**The following query can get us the expected output:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project:{
      "_id":0,
      "count":{
        $size:{
          $filter:{
            "input":{
              $objectToArray:"$data.valobjs.vals",
            },
            "as":"value",
            "cond":{
              $eq:["$$value.v.isValid",false]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]).pretty()
```

**Output:**

```
{ "count" : 4 }
```